# Design for scalable periodic queue message batching

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, batch-processing

We currently have a distributed setup where we are publishing events to SQS and we have an application which has multiple hosts that drains messages from the queue and does some transformation over it and transmits to interested parties. I have a use case where the receiving end point has scalability concerns with the message volume and hence we would like to batch these messages periodically (say every 15 mins) in the application before sending it. 
The incoming message rate is around 200 messages per second and each message is no more than 10 KB. This system need not be real time, but would definitely be a good to have and also the order is not important (its okay if a batch containing older messages gets sent first).

1. One approach that I can think of is maintaining an embedded database within the application (each host) that batches the events and another thread that runs periodically and clears the data.
2. Another approach could be to create timestamped buckets in a a distributed key-value store (s3, dynamo etc.) where we write the message to the correct bucket based the messages time stamp and we periodically clear the buckets.

We can run into several issues here, since the messages would be out of order a bucket might have already been cleared (can be solved by having a default bucket though), would need to accurately decide when to clear a bucket etc.

The way I see it, at least two components would be required one which does the batching into a temporary storage and another that clears it.

Any feedback on the above approaches would help, also it looks like a common problem are they any existing solutions that I can leverage ?

Thanks

Comment: How unstable is your endpoint? SQS has limited built in batch capabilities: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-batch-api.html. Given your message size of 10kb and max batch size for SQS of 64kb, you might get a very straightforward solution batching up messages 6 at a time. This would lower your max messages per second to 35 - batches - or so.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Unfortunately the end point is designed to handle requests of large size (order of dozens of mega bytes) and might not be able to process more couple thousand requests per hour.

Comment: So given that I think having each host sort it out would get messy. Instead I'd suggest S3 buckets, as opposed to setting up a another key-value store, because you are already on Amazon's infrastructure. You'll need to goof with how many objects you can easily store and retrieve therein, but I can imagine doing it with a single bucket provided gathering up objects there is not too tedious.